# Distributed Availability group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can I add two 2 secondary AG groups to distributed AG group?
Ex:-(I have AG1, AG2 & AG3 ) Assume I am creating a Distributed AG between AG1&AG2, Meanwhile is it possible to add my AG3 in my distributed group?

Answer (score 0):

> Assume I am creating a Distributed AG between AG1&AG2, Meanwhile is it possible to add my AG3 in my distributed group?

No, you cannot add it to an already existing distributed availability group. Your options are to hub and spoke it or daisy chain it. Only two availability groups can belong to a single distributed availability group as it is currently implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can connect directly with AG1 or you can do daisy-chaining like AG1->AG2->AG3
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16